# Capitalizing the first letter of each word, converting the rest to lowercase

Tags: c

My task is:

> Capitalize the first letter of each word, converting the rest to lowercase.

input      `PrOgRaMmInG  MeThOd`

expected output `Programming Method`

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SIZE 100

void xoa(char s[100], int v)
{
    int len = strlen(s);
    for (int i = v; i < len; i++)
        s[i] = s[i + 1]; 
    s[len - 1] = '\0'; 
}

void xoakt(char *s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
        if (s[i] == ' ' && s[i + 1] == ' ') 
        {
            xoa(s, i);
            i--;
        }
    
    if (s[0] == ' ')
        xoa(s, 0);
    
    if (s[strlen(s) - 1] == ' ')
        xoa(s, strlen(s) - 1);
}

int main()
{
    char s[100];

    printf("Enter string: ");
    fgets(s, 100, stdin);
    xoakt(s);
    
    for (int i = 1; i < strlen(s); i++) 
    {
        s[i] = tolower(s[i]);
        if (s[i] == " ")
        {
            break;
            for (int j = strlen(s); j >= strlen(s); j--)
            {   
                if (s[j] >= " ")
                {
                    s[j] = tolower(s[j]);
                    if (s[j] == " ")
                    { 
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

My program outputs `Programming method`
but I need it to output `Programming Method`.

I'm just a newbie and I don't know how to do it
Please help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A good starting point would be to enable compiler warnings, and *fix them* before even attempting to run your code.  For example, all of your comparisons of `s[i]` to `" "` should have produced warnings about comparing an integer to a pointer.  Do you understand the difference between `' '` and `" "`?  The first is an integer whose value is the character code for a space.  The second is pointer to a string.  It doesn't make sense to compare individual characters in a string to a pointer to a string.  Your compiler should have warned about that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. The title should be clear and descriptive enough to explain its content to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results. Your current title says nothing that means anything. Also, you'll find your experiences at SO will be much better if you take the time to complete the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Wow, it may be a difference in language, but generally descriptive function names are helpful, especially for those that have to help with your code. If it is a language difference, that's fine, but `xoa()` and `xoakt()` don't seem to make much sense. Closest I get is a roadside campground you saw every 50 miles or so driving in the States as kids (it's actually KOA Campgrounds ... but you get the drift...)

Comment: Sorry i'm good at English so i don't know how to describe it better . Thankyou for your comments

Comment: @Chow Question has input `.      PrOgRaMmInG  MeThOd    `.  Are the spaces before and after `PrOgRaMmInG  MeThOd` important?

Answer (score 3):

To convert a *string* to *title case*, use a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).  Here we need to keep track of the prior character's white-space-ness.

Just a single pass through the string with no need to call `strlen()`.

```
#include <ctype.h>

// Convert string to title case.
char *title_case(char *s) {
  // Best to use `is...()` functions with `unsigned char` values.
  unsigned char *us = (unsigned char *) s;
  bool prior_is_whitespace = true;
  while (*us) {
    if (prior_is_whitespace) {
      *us = (unsigned char) toupper(*us);
    } else {
      *us = (unsigned char) tolower(*us);
    }
    prior_is_whitespace = isspace(*us);
    us++;
  }
  return s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- in function `xoa` you have undefined behavior on `s[len - 1] = '\0';` if `s` points to an empty string.
- in `xoakt` recomputing the length of `s` at each iteration is costly. Also `s[strlen(s) - 1]`  has undefined behavior if the string argument is empty or only contains spaces.
- in `main`, you should test for failure of `fgets()` which returns `NULL` at end of file and leaves `s` unchanged, causing undefined behavior as `s` is uninitialized.
- `char` arguments to `tolower` and other functions from `<ctype.h>` should be cast as `(unsigned char)` to avoid undefined behavior on negative `char` values on platforms where `char` is a signed type.
- `s[i] == " "` is meaningless: you are comparing a `char` with a string (a `char *`). You should write `s[i] == ' '` instead.
- the inner `for` loop never executes after the `break` statement.
- if you removed this `break` statement, `for (int j = strlen(s); j >= strlen(s); j--)` would only run once with `s[j]` being the null terminator.
- in this inner loop, `s[j] >= " "` and `s[j] == " "` are incorrect for the reason mentioned above.

You can use a single loop to solve this problem as shown in the modified version below:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char s[100];

    printf("Enter string: ");
    if (fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin)) {
        size_t i = 0;
        size_t j = 0;

        for (;;) {
            // skip spaces
            while (isspace((unsigned char)s[i]) {
                i++;
            }
            // stop if end of string
            if (s[i] == '\0')
                break;
            // insert a space between words
            if (j > 0) {
                s[j++] = ' ';
            }
            // capitalize the first letter of the word
            s[j++] = (char)toupper((unsigned char)s[i++];
            // lower case the remaining letters
            while (s[i] != '\0' && !isspace((unsigned char)s[i])) {
                s[j++] = (char)tolower((unsigned char)s[i++];
            }
        }
        // set the null terminator (necessary if spaces were removed)
        s[j] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Breaking large problems down into smaller problems makes problem solving easier.

In this case, we need to be able to solve a number of small problems:

- Downcasing an entire string.
- Advancing a char pointer past spaces.
- Advancing *to* the next space.
- Using the previous two problems to collect an array of pointers to the first characters of each word in a string. *(Note this does not account for punctuation.)*

Each of these is a straightforward function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void downcase_string(char *str) {
    for (; *str; str++)
        *str = tolower(*str);
}

char *advance_past_space(char *str) {
    for (; *str && isspace(*str); str++);
    return str;
}

char *advance_to_space(char *str) {
    for (; *str && !isspace(*str); str++);
    return str;
}

size_t first_letters_of_words(char *str, char **ptrs) {
    size_t found = 0;

    while (*str) {
        str = advance_past_space(str);
        if (!str) break;

        ptrs[found++] = str;
        str = advance_to_space(str);
    }

    return found;
}
```

Once we have pointers to the first letter in each word, it's easy to iterate over those pointers and upcase the characters they point to.

```
int main(void) {
    char str[] = "hello world foo bar";

    char *first_letters[sizeof(str)];
    size_t found = first_letters_of_words(str, first_letters);;

    downcase_string(str);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < found; ++i)
        *first_letters[i] = toupper(*first_letters[i]);

    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Result:

```
Hello World Foo Bar
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


void myFunction(char *my_string) {
    int string_length;
    scanf("%[^\n]", my_string);

    string_length = strlen(my_string);
    my_string[0] = toupper(my_string[0]);  // converts first char to uppercase

    for (int i = 1; i < string_length; i++) {
        // if whitespace is found
        if (my_string[i - 1] == ' ') {
            my_string[i] = toupper(my_string[i]);
        } else {
            my_string[i] = tolower(my_string[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char my_string[100];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    myFunction(my_string);
    printf(my_string);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It [does work](https://godbolt.org/z/j9EsdhcdW)   Good job and congratulations!

Comment: Make sure to test your own solution. If you're not sure if it addresses the OP's needs because those are unclear, use a comment to request clarity.

Comment: it works but the space between "Programming" and "Method" is not removed, your code is very simple for me to understand. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

I change main function like below.

```
int main()
{
    char s[100];
    printf("Enter string: ");
    fgets(s,100,stdin);
        xoakt(s);
    
    for(int i=strlen(s)-1;i>=0;i--){
      if(i==0) {s[i]= toupper(s[i]); break;}
      if(s[i-1]==' ') s[i]=toupper(s[i]);
      else s[i]=tolower(s[i]);
    }
    printf("%s",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Am I right?

I hope my answer can help you.

Good luck.

Comment: [Your solution](https://godbolt.org/z/obqbz73qs) also works.  Good job!

Answer (score 1):

The output you desire is called title case, and here is one way to do that:

Runnable Code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/nW49bKq6K).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/*----------------------------------------------------
    title_case()
*----------------------------------------------------*/
void title_case(char *buff)
{
char *ptr = buff;
int done = 0, new_word = 1; 

    while (!done && buff)
    {
        switch(*ptr)
        {
            case '\0':      
                done = 1;  
            break;

            case ' ': 
                new_word = 1;
                ptr++;
            break;

            default:
            break;
        }
        if(new_word)
            *ptr = (char)toupper(*ptr);
        else
            *ptr = (char)tolower(*ptr);
        new_word = 0;
        ptr++;
    }
}

int main()
{
char buff[25] =  "PrOgRaMmInG MeThOd";
    
    printf("%s after title_case() is ", buff );
    title_case(buff);
    printf("%s.\n", buff );
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
PrOgRaMmInG MeThOd after title_case() is Programming Method.
```

Answer (score 1):

The initial implementation posted does not use two functions that I would have expected it to use, `isspace` and `toupper`.

A function like this should work.

```
void do_title_case_conversion(char *str)
{
    int raise = 1; /* if zero, set case to lower */

    for(char *pc=str; *pc; pc++)
    {
        if (isspace(*pc))
            raise = 1; /* between words */
        else if (raise && isalpha(*pc))
        { /* first letter of new word */
            *pc = toupper(*pc);
            raise = 0;
        }
        else if (!raise && isupper(*pc))
            *pc = tolower(*pc); /* middle of word */
    }
}
```